# How do I use command blocks to testfor multiple blocks(a specified block)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I use command blocks to test for multiple blocks(a specified block)?  I've been looking and no website will tell me. I have tried using many test for block but just lined up, but it takes long amounts of time and is very tedious.

Comment: You do realize that `/testforblocks` is a command, right? Here's the link: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/testforblocks

Comment: i know that but it doesn't work the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain `execute detect`, for example like this:

```
/execute if block ~ ~-1 ~ gold_block if block ~ ~2 ~ diamond_block run say hi
```

This makes every player who stands on a gold block and under a diamond block say "hi".

Comment: this is very helpful... i was using it to make a minigame thankz

Comment: You can mark it as accepted to indicate that it solved your problem.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute if block ~ ~-1 ~ gold_block if block ~ ~2 ~ diamond_block run ...`